# How to replace whitespace from column names in csv logstash import

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to ingest a csv file to include data on the elasticsearch server on the existing index. The csv file contains whitespaces in header column names.
I also referred elastic discussions but those answers are not solved my issues "[the Stuck in Logstash](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/stuck-in-logstash/269704), [Removing whitespace from column in csv import](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/removing-whitespace-from-column-in-csv-import/92702) So here I am posting a new question.

Here is an example "MOBILE NO" should be renamed to "MOBILE_NO". Can I achieve this in logstash import?

This is my pipeline configuration(on windows)

```
input{
file{
    path => "E:\abc\xyz\johny.*csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "NUL"
}
}
filter{
csv{
    separator => ","
    columns => ["STATUS_TYPE","GENDER","AGE","MOBILE NO","HOUSE NO"]
}    
ruby  {
    code => "
            hash = event.to_hash
            hash.each{|k,v| event.set(k.gsub(/ /,'_'),v) && event.remove(k) if k.include?(' ')  }
        "
}
}
output{
elasticsearch{
    hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
    index => "heaven_search"
}
stdout{
    codec => rubydebug
}
}
```

Whenever I am running the above config file, I got logs and at the end i got this message `[2022-07-19T00:40:07,063][INFO ][logstash.agent] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}` but nothing changed after the message. And no data indexing into elasticsearch.

Comment: @Val hope you can answer.

Comment: Are you sure about this path `johny.*csv`?

Comment: @Val Yes, the file path is correct. I want to import all files which are extension `.csv` on the directory. I removed the backslash `path => "E:/abc/xyz/johny.*csv"` and ran again. Still stuck at `Pipelines running`.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is where the `*` is located inside the file name. Look carefully

Comment: @Val I pointed the path to a specific file instead of `.*csv` and ran logstash again. This time It showed me a different error like `Marking url as dead.`

Comment: [LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError] Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://localhost:9200/_bulk][Manticore::SocketTimeout] Read timed out

Comment: {:url=>http://localhost:9200/, :error_message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://localhost:9200/_bulk][Manticore::SocketTimeout] Read timed out", :error_class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError"}

Comment: 1) try `*.csv` instead of `.*csv`

Comment: 2) what do you get when running `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200` ?

Comment: `{  "name" : "DESKTOP-SDFDSF",  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",  "cluster_uuid" : "Xh7IugWITgmEnNYwbLIfSg",  "version" : {"number" : "8.3.2","build_type" : "zip",
    "build_hash" : "8b0b1f23fbebecc3c88e4464319dea8989f374fd","build_date" : "2022-07-06T15:15:15.901688194Z","build_snapshot" : false, "lucene_version" : "9.2.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
`

Comment: Did you try `http` or `https` ? Because as of ES 8, HTTPS communications are the default

Comment: I am getting message `Invalid response` in browser when I use `https://localhost:9200/` .